# День программиста. Как найти?

Tags: java, calendar, simpledateformat

**Условие задачи:**

> *День программиста отмечается в 255-й день года (при этом 1 января считается нулевым днем). Требуется написать программу, которая определит дату (месяц и число григорианского календаря), на которую приходится День программиста в заданном году.*
>
> Выводить дату необходимо в формате **DD/MM/YYYY**, где DD — число, MM — номер месяца (01 — январь, 02 — февраль), YYYY — год в десятичной записи
>
> А вводиться **целое число** от 1 до 9999 включительно, год нашей эры.

Вот код:

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
int YEAR = in.nextInt();

SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
Calendar gCal = new GregorianCalendar(YEAR, 0, 0);

gCal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, 256);

String dayP = sdf.format(gCal.getTime());
System.out.println(dayP);
```

Не могу понять проблему. В компиляторе всё проходит как мне нужно, в Високосные года день 12/09/2000, в другие он 13/09/2100.

Но сайт не принимает данный код и не проходит 6 тест, не понимаю какие данные не считываются. Может проблемы с **Calendar** и **SDF**? Просто небольшой опыт с ними, и я воспользовался этим.

Comment: Так все правильно, 2000 - високосный год, а 2100 - нет.

Comment: Сайт указывает что не проходит все тесты, где то что не правильно, хмм

Comment: пользуйтесь java8 , а если нет такой возможности, то - joda time, там все просто LocalDate.of(2018, 01, 01).plusDays(255);

Comment: хм, а что в Java8?

Comment: а в java 8 есть пакет java.time,по сути это joda time только уже из коробки. ну, разумеется, имеется в виду 8 и выше

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
int y = in.nextInt();
boolean isLeap = y % 4 == 0 && (y % 100 != 0 || y % 400 == 0);
int d = isLeap ? 12 : 13;

System.out.printf("%02d/09/%04d", d, y);
```

Comment: Кто может мне объяснить ("%02d/09/%04d", d, y), принцип работы данной строки? из моих знаний знаю что сначало тип указывают а потом через запятые переменные как тут, но для чего %02? и %04?

Comment: Ответ, мне помог. Спасибо, но всё же не понимаю той строчки. Объясните, буду благодарен

Comment: `%04d` - вывести int в 4 символа дополняя слева нулями.

Comment: Ух, как сильно, благодарю. а "d" что означает? Как узнать об этом больше? Что это за операция?

Comment: `d` означает `int` в десятичной системе счисления (decimal).

Answer (score 2):

GregorianCalendar по умолчанию поступит как Григорианский календарь [только после года 1582](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/GregorianCalendar.html).

Вы можете использовать метод [setGregorianChange](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/GregorianCalendar.html#setGregorianChange-java.util.Date-) и метод [setCalendar](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html#setCalendar-java.util.Calendar-) для изменения поведения:

```
  SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
  GregorianCalendar gCal = new GregorianCalendar();
  gCal.setGregorianChange(new Date(Long.MIN_VALUE));

  gCal.set(YEAR, 0, 0);
  gCal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, 256);

  sdf.setCalendar(gCal);
  String dayP = sdf.format(gCal.getTime());
  System.out.println(dayP);
```